# Spark Structured Streaming using python and Kafka giving error

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting the below error when trying to initiate a readStream for kafka, my Kafka is up and running and I tested it multiple times to ensure it is processing.
Kafka topic is created as well.

'''

```
kafka_df = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "mytopic") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()
```

'''

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users//PycharmProjects/SparkStreaming/PySparkKafkaStreaming.py", line 18, in 
kafka_df = spark.readStream 
File "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\streaming.py", line 420, in load
return self._df(self._jreader.load())
File "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in **call**
return_value = get_return_value(
File "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 134, in deco
raise_from(converted)
File "", line 3, in raise_from
**pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;**

Comment: You need to run or package and build with the dependencies for KAFKA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the kafka dependencies to run this ! For pyspark, you can download the jar and put in spark/jars directory or import the dependencies in the sparkSession inital config.
Please, follow this [kafka-structured streaming docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

I hope I've helped, anything you could ask me, thanks !

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on that. Here is my SparkSession where I am including the jar details:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master("local[3]") \
        .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullOnShutdown","true") \
        .config("spark.jar.packages","org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1") \
        .getOrCreate()

Comment: I tried to put the code here, but it didn't fit, so I'll be posting the github link I used:
https://github.com/indiacloudtv/structuredstreamingkafkapyspark/blob/master/pyspark_structured_streaming_kafka_demo.py